# Whatsapp: Scheduled sync to NAS storage of photos. How to include Group Media?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

I have a regular sync on my phone to backup photos to my NAS storage over wifi. It runs automatically overnight and I never have to remember to do it.

I include in the sync:
internal storage/Android/media/com.whatsapp/Whatsapp/Media/WhatsApp Images

But this folder does not contain all shared photos, only photos sent directly to me, and Group Media is missing.

What is the path for Group Media?  It's clearly on my phone somewhere as I can view the images offline. Any guidance appreciated.

Comment: I checked my `/WhatsApp Images` folder and it contains photos from WhatsApp groups. Are the images shown on the gallery apps?

Answer (score 0):

Other photos are encrypted.  They are not available directly in the file system. All you can do is to rely on the automatic backup.  You can only access the images that you sent or the ones sent to you directly.

Comment: I checked my `/WhatsApp Images` folder and it contains photos from WhatsApp groups and not encrypted. Could you clarify by "encrypted"? Is it a feature that can be enabled?